# Can Rainmeter "dock" like the Windows taskbar, Desktop Sidebar, or Google Desktop sidebar?

Tags: desktop, taskbar, dock, sidebar, rainmeter

Well, I think that's the most succinct title I've ever had. Not sure what to say here, save for restating the question.

Can Rainmeter "dock" to the walls of a display like the Windows taskbar, Desktop Sidebar, or Google Desktop sidebar do by default? When I maximize an application, I would like for Rainmeter to stay visible by adjusting the bounds of the display (as the others do).

Moral of the story is, I'm loving the Rainmeter and all, but I hate having to have all of these different apps that all have their various nuances to learn and adapt to. I would like to be able to replace with Rainmeter if at all possible.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Manual you will find DesktopWorkArea http://rainmeter.net/RainCMS/?q=Settings Those settings can be adjusted to change the areas that windows will cover.

Comment: I did eventually figure this one out, but thanks! ;)